# How to check registered email in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

---

It is working fine if there is only one data but when there is more than one data, it still register with existing email. So i want it not to register for the same email when there are more than one data.

```
$post = $this->input->post();

    $input_email        = $this->input->post('client_email');
    $available_email    = $this->Common_model->selectData('admin', 'admin_email', '');
    $outputArray        = [];

    foreach($available_email as $row) {
        $outputArray[] = $row->admin_email;
    }

    $avail_email = implode(', ', $outputArray);
    
    if($post) {

        if($input_email == $avail_email) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'The email you entered is already registered with us. Please try again');
            redirect('admin/admin-register');
        } else {
           **Run register
        }
    } else {
        **error
    }
```

Comment: can show your model? if registered email is supposed to be unique, model should return either 0 (doesn't exist) or 1 (exists)

Comment: If you.want to prevent a signup using an email that's already registered, the easiest way would be to enforce `is_unique` on the form validation. Have you tried that?